# get current user not working

Tags: user-meta, users

I was trying this code to get current user info, but showing nothing. My WordPress version is  3.3.1

```
<?php
    wp_get_current_user();
    /**
     * @example Safe usage: $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
     * if ( !($current_user instanceof WP_User) )
     *     return;
     */
    echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . '<br />';
    echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . '<br />';
    echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . '<br />';
    echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . '<br />';
    echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . '<br />';
    echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . '<br />';
?>
```

**The output is:**

Username:

User email:

User first name:

User last name:

User display name:

User ID:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried to go with the "Safe usage" alternative given in the commented section?

I honestly don't have any experience with `wp_get_current_user()`, since I never use it, but anyhow, this ought to work:

```
global $current_user;

echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . '<br />';
echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . '<br />';
echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . '<br />';
echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . '<br />';
echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . '<br />';
echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID;
```

`wp_get_current_user()` should do the same, as it is nothing but a wrapper for the first two lines above, nonetheless, the above has got to work.

Answer (score 2):

> Prior to **Wordpress 4.5** `get_currentuserinfo()` was an acceptable option, but is
>   now deprecated, in favor of `wp_get_current_user()`.

*You can set the `wp_get_current_user()` as a variable to easily access it in your function or page:*

[`$current_user = wp_get_current_user();`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/c5e3716c11ecdf89fb7d24d0dbff5085865763ad/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L68)

**Example:**

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . '<br />';
    echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . '<br />';
    echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . '<br />';
    echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . '<br />';
    echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . '<br />';
    echo 'User ID: '. $current_user->ID . '<br />';
    echo 'User avatar: ' . get_avatar( $current_user->ID, 64 ) . '<br />';

} else {

    echo 'User not logged in.';

}
```

**Also, it's important to make sure this is all being done after `init` to avoid blank output.**

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can get current user:

```
global $current_user;
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
```

After that, you can use `$current_user->ID` where you want.

Example:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . '--';
    echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . '--';
    echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . '--';
    echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . '--';
    echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . '--';
    echo 'User ID: '. $current_user->ID . '--';
} else {
    echo 'User not logged in.';
}
```

Comment: Why do you need/use the global?

Comment: Mark I just updated the answer, but to answer your question, the global is unnecessary as that is the main reason to use `wp_get_current_user()` (click the link to see where the function accesses the global if you're curious as to how it works).